# All k-nearest weight-balanced neighbors

Tags: neo4j, graph-algorithm

There is an undirected weighted graph. The weights are the costs.
I would like to find all the k-nearest neighbour. (less than "k", but more than predefined "l")

When you found the most similar connected nodes, you need to "exclude" them from the graph, but taking care of not to lose the connectivity of other nodes relying on them, so maximize the number of k-nearest groups. I wouldn't like to see "n/group size" iteration.

The result must include cost and partition. (there can be unconnected graphs next to each other)
Undirected is especially bi-directed and undirected costs, however, it will be summed together. The higher/lower the two numbers relatively are, the higher/lower the combined costs.

I tracked down some of the algorithms (MST /all Shortest paths/similarity/centrality), but none of them was matching my expectation.
This algorithm just one of my challenges, so reusing is more preferable (saving time).
Any idea, how to solve this problem?

Efficiency and parallelism do matter as it can be billions of nodes, but not a priority as they can be clustered in different ways initially.

Comment: "you need to "exclude" them from the graph, but taking care of not to lose the connectivity of other nodes relying on them"
Can you please explain in more detail what would you like to achieve... some examples would be welcomed too!

Comment: Example: You have 20 buildings you need to visit, you need to spend 1 hour in each building. Between some of the building, the travel cost is known. You have 3 employees. You are paying employees on visits. Pls. share the buildings among the three employees by maximizing and balancing the visited buildings on an 8-hour job with minimum fuel cost. (each employee will be paid some money if he visits min. 2 buildings, but won't be overpaid after 6 visits or so.) Community detection algorithms seem to be promising, the real example is quite different, but I hope you get the idea. Graph can be huge

Comment: You can just calculate the fuel according to known travel cost. 3 employees can't cross each others route. So if you remove it from the available route, another employee has less chance to reach an untouched node. As I'm no expert on neo4j field I feel a month later I would formalize my question differently. Graph data science a little bit less painful to comprehend than the previous library.

Comment: At the moment my guess is, I need to use a community detection algorithm, and restrict the number of nodes somehow in each community.